# How do I implement Campaign tracking with Cordova after registration only?

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-analytics, affiliate, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I have a task to track users inside the application who have downloaded this application in AppStore or PlayMarket by clicking on the affiliate's link. For now I use Google Analytics to track downloads. But have no idea how to track registrations. 
Project stack:
- JavaScript (Vue)
- NodeJS
Any ideas.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use event tracking via analytic, read [this](https://www.gravitatedesign.com/blog/event-tracking-google-analytics/)

You could also use Google Tag Manager, read [this](https://www.gravitatedesign.com/blog/google-tag-manager-tutorial-event-tracking/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already use google tag manager. My goal is not to lose these tags inside the application after installation. More precisely, have access to them

Comment: so what is the problem ?